# Python - Iteration of Grade

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a code where it gets the keys from the dictionary, calculate the average and then create an iteration where it gets the average of each student and shows the grade by letter, but I'm getting an error and can't figure out what's wrong.

Here's the code:

```
graDict = {'John': ['Math', [90, 75, 77]], 'Adam': ['Math', [70, 75, 87, 77]]}
#calc average
def Average(graDict):
    total = 0
    value = graDict[sName][1]
    for key, value in graDict.items():
        total += float(value)
    return total / len(graDict)
#error: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

#iteration
for sName in list(graDict.keys()):
    value = Average(graDict) #getting average calc above
    if value > 90:
        print("{} earns grade = A".format(sName))
```

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Thank you

Comment: aside: `value` in `for key, value in graDict.items():` is overwriting the previously defined `value`

Answer (score 1):

You should be looping over the list `value` that you created instead of `graDict.items()`. You could just sum the list into your total variable.

```
def Average(graDict):
    total = sum(graDict[sName][1])
    return total / len(graDict)
```

Edit: iterate over correct list (variable name changed to `grades` to be more explicit.)

```
graDict = {'John': ['Math', [90, 75, 77]], 'Adam': ['Math', [70, 75, 87, 77]]}
#calc average
def Average(graDict):
    total = 0
    grades = graDict[sName][1]
    for grade in grades:
        total += float(value)
    return total / len(graDict)

#iteration
for sName in list(graDict.keys()):
    value = Average(graDict) #getting average calc above
    if value > 90:
        print("{} earns grade = A".format(sName))
```

Comment: I'm not supposed to use sum tho

Comment: Thank you! But what if I want to append the values into the dictionary?

Comment: You can’t append to a dictionary. You can add ```key value``` pairs or append to the list you have in the dictionary. 

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
graDict = {'John': ['Math', [90, 75, 77]], 'Adam': ['Math', [70, 75, 87, 77]]}
#calc average
def Average(graDict):
    total = 0
    values = graDict[sName][1]
    for i in values:
        total += i
    return total / len(values)

#iteration
for sName in list(graDict.keys()):
    value = Average(graDict) #getting average calc above
    print("{0}:{1}".format(sName,value))
    if value > 90:
        print("{} earns grade = A".format(sName))
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you, I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but my feedback was recorded.

Answer (score 0):

A more pythonic answer is :

```
>>> graDict = {'John': ['Math', [90, 75, 77]], 'Adam': ['Math', [70, 75, 87, 77]]}
>>> l = ['{} {} average {:.2f}'.format(k, v[0], sum(v[1])/len(v[1])) for k,v in graDict.items()]
>>> print(l)
['John Math average 80.67', 'Adam Math average 77.25']
```

[Edit]
However, it seems your input data should have dict of dicts instead of dict of lists in order to accommodate multiple subjects. In that case a slightly complicated comprehension would be required. A comprehension based solution may be like below:

```
>>> graDictX = {'John': {'Math': [90, 75, 77], 'English': [80, 70, 90 ]}, 'Adam': {'Math': [70, 75, 87, 77]}}
>>> ret = [val for sublist in
...                   [['{} {} average {:.2f}'.format(k, x, sum(y) / len(y)) for x, y in v.items()]
...                    for k,v in graDictX.items()] for val in sublist]
>>> print(ret)
['John Math average 80.67', 'John English average 80.00', 'Adam Math average 77.25']
```

Comment: What if I want to append the values into the dictionary?
def Average(graDict):
    total = 0
    values = graDict[sName][1]
    for i in values:
        total += i 
     #have to get this total that makes the grade sum and append to dictionary
    return total / len(values)
        #have to get the return in Average(graDict) and append to Dictionary

Comment: This is simple, if you want it on your original data set, then it would be like : ```graDict = {'John': ['Math', [90, 75, 77]], 'Adam': ['Math', [70, 75, 87, 77]]}
l = {k : (v[0], sum(v[1])/len(v[1])) for k,v in graDict.items()}
print(l)
```